# How to use sync call in GWT or wait for call to be completed

Tags: gwt, web

This method is updating test variable. But the problem is that if condition does not wait for call to be completed instead it executes and produces wrong result. Any suggestion.

```
((GWTServiceUsersAsync)GWT.create(GWTServiceUsers.class)).checkSession(callbackcheck);

if(test==0) {
  MessageBox.alert("Access denied", "Access denied, please log in", null);
  return 0;
} else {
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: You **desperately** need to re-read the GWT documentation on RPC.

Comment: You must use the callback to get something from the server. This is called Asynchronous programming and that's why you have the Async interfaces. Please study the GWT basics before posting questions.

Comment: Brother I know that but problem is that how to stop client thread so the variable is updated.

Comment: You cannot "stop" the client thread, it is impossible. You provide a callback. You have a fundamental misunderstanding of RPC. Again, go read the docs.

Comment: @TravisWebb actually it is possible,if you use synchronous XmlHttpRequest , but the end result is terrible since the whole browser will freeze until the request is finished. But it is very useful in some cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Async means that you don't know when the callback will occur which is why it doesn't wait. Also in java we generally use booleans(true, false) not numbers. Here is an example on what you would do:

```
 GWTServiceUsersAsync service = GWT.create(GWTServiceUsersAsync.class)
    service.checkSession(new AsyncCallback() {
       public void onSuccess(boolean test) {
         if(!test) {
            MessageBox.alert("Access denied", "Access denied, please log in", null);
            responseHandlingMethod(true);
         }
         responseHandlingMethod(test);
       }

        public void onFailure(Exception e) {
             responseHandlingMethod(test);
        }
    }
```

The rest of your code after check session can then be handled in responseHandlingMethod. I would recommend following some of the tutorials that google have like [Google RPC tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC).